# Artefacts in image when using scipy.ndimage.rotate with alpha channel

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy

I'm getting artefacts when rotating an image with transparency, but it could be the fault of the way I'm applying the transparency mask? Does any one have any ideas why its happening? What I should do instead or how to remedy it?

I've noticed it happens the worst while rotating, but the artefacts can stay once the objects angular motion stops.

Should I rotate the mask and tree together in one array?

Any suggestions welcome :)

Basic Code:

```
#get mask and sprite
mask_rot = rotate(mask.copy(), degrees, reshape=True, mode='constant', cval=0.0)
sprite_rot = rotate(sprite.copy(), degrees, reshape=True, mode='constant', cval=0.0)

#get insertion position
pos = self.centroid

#get array position
x_start = int(round(pos[0] - (sprite_rot.shape[1] / 2)))
y_start = int(round(pos[1] - (sprite_rot.shape[0] / 2)))
x_end = int(x_start + sprite_rot.shape[1])
y_end = int(y_start + sprite_rot.shape[0])

#inset into position

board_slice = self.board.board_copy[y_start:y_start+sprite_rot.shape[0],x_start:x_start+sprite_rot.shape[1],:]

self.board.board_copy[y_start:y_start+sprite_rot.shape[0],x_start:x_start+sprite_rot.shape[1],:] = (sprite_rot * mask_rot) + (board_slice* (1-mask_rot))
```

I'm using this image (but it happens with any).

[image]

An example of the issue.

[image]

Comment: Are you using skimage rotate? If so, I do not see any argument called "reshape". Do you mean to use the argument "resize"? See https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rotate

Comment: @fmw42 He's using `scipy.ndimage.rotate`, not scikit-image. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html

Comment: `@rayryeng` Thanks for the correction. I was not sure, since he did not post his code showing his imports.

Comment: Sorry it was in the post title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone reading this, I switched to skimage.transforms.rotate and all works as expected now.

It works in a very similar way to the scipy version but no artefacts thus far.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the PNG being 32-bit color (with 8-bit alpha) and GIF only supporting 256 colors and binary alpha. The rotation of the alpha channel changes the alpha values slightly at the boundary. So some pixels that are slightly less than 50% opaque become slightly more than 50% opaque when binarized by saving to GIF.

Basically, the PNG image has 8-bit alpha and the GIF frames have binary alpha. When rotated and binarized some (partially) transparent (i.e., antialiased) pixels at the boundary of the alpha channel become opaque and show the color underneath. So you need a better color quantization tool applied before rotating. See Python Wand at http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.2/, which is based upon ImageMagick, to reduce colors the same way. Or see PIL im.quantize() at http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm to reduce colors.

Comment: The gif was just an example. I'm using openCV to display the image.